# Keydown event does not share its unused keys with the control

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a keydown form event to allow the user to cursor down through the records.  This works well.

I would also like them to be able to edit fields in that record.  That does not work.

I had thought that the KeyPreview form property would allow the form to share any unused keys with the underlying control, but it seems to suck up all keys entered so they are not available to any control

Is there a way to achieve what I need?

Here is the code

```vb
Private Sub Form_KeyDown(KeyCode As Integer, Shift As Integer)

    If (Shift And acAltMask) = 0 And (Shift And acShiftMask) = 0 And (Shift And acCtrlMask) = 0 Then
        Select Case KeyCode
        Case vbKeyDown
            If CurrentRecord <> RecordsetClone.RecordCount Then
                DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNext
            Else
                'Do nothing
            End If
        Case vbKeyUp
            If CurrentRecord <> 1 Then
                DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acPrevious
            Else
                'Do nothing
            End If
        End Select
    End If
    KeyCode = 0
End Sub
```

Comment: Please share your code if you want us to help you with it (any attempts, including the errors you've encountered).

Comment: Here is my code - if I enable it, non of my controls work (ie accept text)   
'Private Sub Form_KeyDown(KeyCode As Integer, Shift As Integer)
'    If (Shift And acAltMask) = 0 And (Shift And acShiftMask) = 0 And (Shift And acCtrlMask) = 0 Then
'        Select Case KeyCode
'        Case vbKeyDown
'            If CurrentRecord <> RecordsetClone.RecordCount Then
'                DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNext
'            Else
'                'Do nothing
'            End If
'            End If
'        End Select
'    End If
'    KeyCode = 0
'End Sub

Comment: sorry - I don't know how to include code in my comment

Comment: Please put it in your question, using formatting. Code in comments is hard to read

Answer (score 1):

Remove this line:

```
KeyCode = 0
```

to pass on the key stroke.